# Override TAB inside a Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, indentation

If I'm typing text in a input field and press `ENTER` the default behavior of all the browsers I know is to submit the form, however if I press `ENTER` inside a textarea a new line is added.

**Is there any way to mimic this behavior (indent, not submit the form) whenever I press `TAB` inside a textarea?** [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/) seems to do it, but in a `canvas` element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't done it myself, but it seems to be possible to override the event handler and catch the key. See e.g. [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas).

Oh and for the JQuery crowd there even is a [plugin](https://github.com/alanhogan/Tabby).

Answer (score 2):

Of course there's a way. Do you use any js library? If not, the idea is just to add a *keydown* event handler on the textarea element, check in the handler if the keyCode of the event equals 9, and if so append a "\t" to the content of the textarea. Prototype snippet:

```
textarea.observe('keydown', function (e) {
  if(e.keyCode==9) {
    e.element().insert("\t");
    e.stop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```js
//'index.js' File
var textarea = document.getElementById('note');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==9) {
    e.element().insert("\t");
    e.stop();
    }
});
```

If you get a 'cannot read property of null' error do this:

```js
//'index.js' File v2
function tab() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('note');
    if(event.keyCode===9) {
        textarea.innerHTML += "\t";
    }
}
```

The HTML should follow suit and look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- Don't Mind the other parts like the style and button tags -->
<!-- If you don't get the error mentioned just remove the 'onkeydown="tab()"'. -->
<html onkeydown="tab()">
    <head>
        <title>Calender</title>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
        <style>
            * {
                background-color: darkgoldenrod;
                color: white;
            }

            textarea {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }

            .newNote {
                background-color: olivedrab;
                color: white;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                box-shadow: none;
                border-radius: 7.5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="newNote" id="newNote" onclick="Note()">New Note</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <textarea wrap="soft" rows="30" cols="100" id="note"
placeholder="Type a Note Here!" title="Note Box"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```