# Getting input string from scanner (keyboard like) device C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, string, input, hardware

Sorry if the question is weirdly worded. I have this credit card scanner, which when the card is swiped, will act as a keyboard and type in the input if you're in a text editor like notepad. I want to use this device in my asp.net 5 mvc 6 application and have it enter that input right into a string variable. The input also starts with a tab, goes to two words separated by a space, then two tabs, then a string of numbers and letters (no more tabs). Those tabs seem to be messing up my input. I tried getting it into an input box and that doesn't work because the tabs change context and make it type the string into the address bar. I am using Microsoft Edge for this. I also tried using:

```
while(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    Console.Write("Waiting for card swipe...");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Again with that, the tab at the start and the ones after the first word following the first tab are messing it up. Any ideas on what method I should be using to get this input into a string variable? Do I have to do something about this tab issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I had to implement a barcode scanner for another application and in the end I resorted to something like [this](https://github.com/aelij/RawInputProcessor) to actually get the raw input. Otherwise .Net will treat all keyboards as one and it will also buffer the input so in the end I resorted to accessing the Win32 device.

Comment: You want to override the standard tab functionality in a web browser? If so, you need some Javascript like here:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas

Comment: with barcode scanners at least you can configure what characters are sent before and after the real value. Check if this is possible with this device, it probably is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referred to in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973927/override-tab-inside-a-browser), you need to override the tab functionality of the web browser to do something different so it's recorded in your test field. You need to implement some JavaScript and then check for the key event number 9, like this:

```
textarea.observe('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==9) {
        e.element().insert("\t");
        e.stop();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I can't see a way around it

[EDIT]
Or you can use the jQuery plugin from [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/taboverride/)